# .load() jquery documentation

Tags: jquery

I want to load a html page to my container when user submits some thing.

I have used

```
$("container").load("page_broken.html",function(responseTxt,statusTxt,xhr){
            if(statusTxt=="success") alert((responseTxt));
        });`
```

but `page_broken.html` has `<!doctype> <html> <head>(linking to css files and jquery) <body>`and notice  my original html file, already has this tags and now when I load my container with this html file

Iam worried these tags gets wrapped inside my container.

http://api.jquery.com/load/ Here is a link which says

`jQuery uses the browser's .innerHTML property to parse the retrieved document and insert it into the current document. During this process, browsers often filter elements from the document such as <html>, <title>, or <head> elements. As a result, the elements retrieved by .load() may not be exactly the same as if the document were retrieved directly by the browser.`

but when i used alert, to see the response,it has `<!doctype> <body> and <html>` tags.

So what would be the solution, is the documentation right? It may return the tags but it may not load? Could anyone explain me this clearly. Thanks

Comment: Where is your alert at? if it's in the success callback, then the alert is simply giving you a raw output of what was returned. html title head and doctype are NOT being inserted into your document. So, Yes. the documentation is correct and the method is doing exactly what it is documented to do.

Comment: @KevinB yes, its in the success callback I did not put the whole function sorry .!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter for .load's success callback is the raw html that was returned from your server. If your server returned doctype head title etc, then that raw html will contain it too. jQuery parses this html and inserts it into the target document using innerHTML. innerHTML will strip those tags from the content because they are invalid at that point.

Comment: Could you tell me the tags that are stripped by the jquery. I have linking to style sheets and jquery script in my head tag, will it parse out head tag and still keep the linking part ? Let me know about this.

Comment: Yes, scripts stylesheets etc are kept, which can result in conflicts. If you specified a selector in your URL, the scripts would be executed FIRST, resulting in a timing issue due to the scripts executing too early.